VR Rendering Issues
I am trying to Render a VR Video to use with a VR-Headset, but I always have a kind of Border in my video (picture at the very Buttom).
For Rendering, I render each Frame as a PNG-File seperately and I am using following Settings for the Camera:

For the Image Output Settings i use following Settings:

For Rendering Settings i use Cycles and GPU computation.
I Render all Frames as PNG Images side-by-side and after this I use the image sequencer to create the video as an  MPEG-4 with H.264 codec.
I tried everything but I still have this annoying border in my Video...
Can you please help me?
Render Settings for Video Output:



Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"
